# How to add custom attribute in Stock-Sku in product view

Tags: magento2, attributes, product-attribute, custom-attributes

i need to add my custom attribute (free shipping, 24h, 48h...) in product view.

This block class is product-info-stock-sku.

[image: How to add custom attribute in Stock-Sku]

Thanks,
Adrz

Comment: have you find answer?

Comment: Nope.. :( I did not find anything

Answer (score 2):

Create xml template in path "app\design\frontend\"YourThemeFirm"\"ThemeName"\Magento_Catalog\layout\catalog_product_view.xml"

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
 <page layout="2columns-right" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
 <body>
 <referenceContainer name="content">
     <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product_view_style" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/style.phtml" after="-"/>
 </referenceContainer>
 <move element="product_view_style" destination="product.info.stock.sku" after="-"/>
 </body>
 </page>
```

Then create phtml template in path "app\design\frontend\"YourThemeFirm"\"ThemeName"\Magento_Catalog\templates\product\view\style.phtml"

```
<?php $_product = $this->getProduct(); ?>
<div class="product attribute style">
<strong class="type"><?php echo __('Style: ')?></strong>
<div class="value" itemprop="style"><?php echo $_product->getData('style_number') ?></div>
</div>
```

Something like that :)

Comment: `<div class="value" itemprop="style"><?php echo $_product->getAttributeText('style_number') ?></div>`